# Example of Signedness Bug in Smart Contracts

Tags: vulnerability

I found an example of underflow bug at:
[Catching Vulnerable Smart Contracts Once and for All](https://2019.icse-conferences.org/details/icse-2019-New-Ideas-and-Emerging-Reults/29/VULTRON-Catching-Vulnerable-Smart-Contracts-Once-and-for-All)

```
contract UnderflowAttack {
 ...
 function withdraw (uint amount) public {
   require(balances[msg.sender] - amount > 0);
   msg.sender.transfer(amount);
   balances[msg.sender] -= amount; //Underflow
 }
 ...
}
```

I feel the above contract also exhibits signedness bug. Can somebody please provide me a more specific example of a signedness bug in smart contract?

Comment: If an underflow happens at `balances[msg.sender] -= amount`, that same underflow also happens at `require(balances[msg.sender] - amount > 0)` because the exact same subtraction is being performed.